# Doctrine 2 пропустить JoinColumn

Tags: orm, doctrine2, doctrine, dql

Здравстуйте, недавно начал изучать Doctrine 2, вроде с трудом продвигаюсь, однако есть непонятные моменты, которые в документации не нашел. 
У меня есть таблица Auto, в ней есть связанные поля (auto_mark, auto_model, auto_body). Так вот, переодически мне надо запрашивать у сущности отдельно марку, отдельно модель. Когда я пытаюсь создать запрос без lefJoin доктрина возращает мне пустоту. Мне не надо чтоб при каждом обращение к сущности он собирал все поля(это сводная таблица), можно ли как то это регулировать? Я понимаю, что можно создать такую же сущность и убрать у нее просто те поля которые мне не надо, но таких похожих запросов у меня около 5ти и не удобно будет потом во всем этом ковыряться. Тоесть регулировать JoinColumn

Запрос(в этом запросе я просто хочу чтоб он вернул мне таблицу, но у меня возвращается пустота, тоесть вообще в прямом смысле нечего не происходит, хотя если я пропишу все LeftJoin(ы) то тогда он мне сделает полную выборку):

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$stm = $qb
    ->select('a')
    ->from('Auto', 'a')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
```

Сущность:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Auto
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="auto", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="auto_mark_id", columns={"auto_mark_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="auto_model_id", columns={"auto_model_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="auto_body_id", columns={"auto_body_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Auto
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="auto_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $autoId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="auto_cod", type="string", length=4, nullable=false)
     */
    private $autoCod;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="auto_img", type="string", length=75, nullable=false)
     */
    private $autoImg;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="auto_type", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $autoType;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="year_start", type="string", length=4, nullable=false)
     */
    private $yearStart;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="year_finish", type="string", length=4, nullable=false)
     */
    private $yearFinish;

    /**
     * @var \AutoMarks
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AutoMarks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="auto_mark_id", referencedColumnName="auto_mark_id")
     * })
     */
    private $autoMark;

    /**
     * @var \AutoModels
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AutoModels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="auto_model_id", referencedColumnName="auto_model_id")
     * })
     */
    private $autoModel;

    /**
     * @var \AutoBody
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AutoBody")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="auto_body_id", referencedColumnName="auto_body_id")
     * })
     */
    private $autoBody;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему не хотите настроить ассоциации, и в нужных местах доставать значения?

например `$auto->getModel()->getName()`
[подробнее тут](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)